Why do WebRTC video streams work on PC but not on iPhone for multi-user calls?
I’m working on a WebRTC-based video calling application using Knockout.js and SignalR, and it works fine on PC for multiple users. However, when I initiate a call from my iPhone (iOS Safari), the receivers don't see each other’s streams. The video containers are added, but the screens remain blank for all receivers, and they can only see me (the sender).
For example:
If I call from my laptop to iPhone 1 and iPhone 2, then everything works fine, consistently.
But if I call from iPhone 1 or iPhone 2 to my laptop and the remaining iPhone, then the sender can see all video streams as usual, but the receivers can't see each other's video stream.
import * as ko from "knockout";
import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr";
import { Modal } from "bootstrap";

let receiverUserIds: string[] = [];

async function getUserMedia() {
  try {
    return await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: true,
      audio: true,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Error fetching user media: ${error}`);
  }
}

function generateRandomNumber(min: number, max: number) {
  // Generate a random number between min and max (inclusive).
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; // Corrected to include max in the range.
}

async function signalrStartHubConnection() {
  try {
    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl("/signalr") // Specify the SignalR hub URL.
      .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information) // Set logging level.
      .withAutomaticReconnect() // Enable automatic reconnection.
      .build(); // Build the SignalR connection.

    await connection.start(); // Start the SignalR connection.
    return connection; // Return the connection object.
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Error starting SignalR connection: ${error}`); // Throw an error if connection fails.
  }
}

async function signalrRegisterWebrtcUserId(
  signalrHubConnection: signalR.HubConnection,
  webrtcUserId: string
) {
  try {
    await signalrHubConnection.invoke("RegisterUser", webrtcUserId); // Invoke SignalR method to register user.
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`Error registering user: ${error}`); // Throw an error if registration fails.
  }
}

// Enums
enum SignalTypeEnum {
  REGISTER = "register",
  INVITE = "invite",
  ICE_CANDIDATE = "ice_candidate",
  ACCEPT = "accept",
  MESH = "mesh",
}

enum RoleEnum {
  SENDER = "sender",
  RECEIVER = "receiver",
}

// Interfaces
interface PeerConnectionsInterface {
  [key: string]: RTCPeerConnection; // Map of user IDs to their respective RTCPeerConnection objects.
}

interface IceCandidatesInterface {
  [key: string]: RTCIceCandidate[];
}

interface IceCandidatesObservableInterface {
  [key: string]: KnockoutObservableArray<RTCIceCandidate>;
}

interface MeshNetworkUserIdsInterface {
  [key: string]: string[];
}

interface SignalDtoInterface {
  signalType: SignalTypeEnum;
  receiverUserId: string; // The user ID of whom you want to send data to.
  senderUserId: string;
  data: string;
  role: RoleEnum;
}

class Conference {
  currentSignal!: SignalDtoInterface;
  userMedia!: MediaStream;
  webrtcIceCandidates: IceCandidatesInterface;
  webrtcGatheredIceCandidates: KnockoutObservable<IceCandidatesObservableInterface>;
  webrtcPeerConnections!: PeerConnectionsInterface; // Optional observable for peer connections.
  webrtcUserId: KnockoutObservable<string>; // Observable for WebRTC user ID.
  webrtcReceiverUserIdsInputField: KnockoutObservable<string>; // Observable input field for receiver user IDs.

  signalrHubConnection!: KnockoutObservable<signalR.HubConnection>; // SignalR hub connection instance.
  signalrConnectionId!: KnockoutObservable<string | null>; // SignalR connection ID, initially null.
  signalrSenderConnectionId: KnockoutObservable<string | null | undefined>; // Observable for the sender's SignalR connection ID.

  isCallToggled: KnockoutObservable<boolean>; // Observable to track call toggle status.

  configuration = {
    iceServers: [
      { urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" }, // STUN server
    ],
  };

  constructor() {
    this.webrtcPeerConnections = {};
    this.webrtcIceCandidates = {};
    this.webrtcGatheredIceCandidates =
      ko.observable<IceCandidatesObservableInterface>({});
    this.webrtcUserId = ko.observable<string>(
      generateRandomNumber(1, 19).toString()
    ); // Generate a random WebRTC user ID and store it as a Knockout observable.
    this.webrtcReceiverUserIdsInputField = ko.observable<string>(""); // Initialize the receiver user IDs input field as an empty string.
    this.signalrSenderConnectionId = ko.observable<string | null | undefined>(); // Initialize as undefined. Should show the ID of the original sender on the receivers screen.
    this.isCallToggled = ko.observable<boolean>(false); // Initialize call toggle state as false.

    // Bind methods to the current instance to ensure `this` context is correct.
    this.toggleCall = this.toggleCall.bind(this);
    this.startCall = this.startCall.bind(this);
    this.stopCall = this.stopCall.bind(this);
    this.acceptCall = this.acceptCall.bind(this);
    this.declineCall = this.declineCall.bind(this);
  }

  addOrUpdateIceCandidate(receiverUserId: string, candidate: RTCIceCandidate) {
    if (!this.webrtcGatheredIceCandidates()[receiverUserId]) {
      this.webrtcGatheredIceCandidates()[receiverUserId] =
        ko.observableArray<RTCIceCandidate>([]);
    }
    this.webrtcGatheredIceCandidates()[receiverUserId].push(candidate); // Knockout will track this.
  }

  async startMediaStream(elementId: string, mediaStream: MediaStream) {
    try {
      const container = document.getElementById("videos"); // Target the container where you want to append the video element.

      if (!container) {
        throw new Error("Container element not found");
      }

      let videoElement = document.getElementById(elementId) as HTMLVideoElement;

      // If the video element doesn't exist, create it and append it to the container
      if (!videoElement) {
        videoElement = document.createElement("video"); // Create a new video element
        videoElement.id = elementId; // Set the element ID
        videoElement.autoplay = true; // Ensure the video plays automatically
        videoElement.muted = false; // Mute the video to avoid echo when playing local stream
        videoElement.playsInline = true; // For mobile devices to support inline video playback
        videoElement.className =
          "w-full bg-black rounded-lg object-contain aspect-video"; // Apply the same styling as other video elements

        // Create a wrapper div if needed (like in your current structure)
        const videoWrapper = document.createElement("div");
        videoWrapper.className = "w-full";

        // Append the video element to the wrapper div
        videoWrapper.appendChild(videoElement);

        // Append the wrapper div to the container
        container.appendChild(videoWrapper);
      }

      // Assign the media stream to the video element
      videoElement.srcObject = mediaStream;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error accessing media devices:", err);
      alert(
        "Error accessing your camera and microphone. Please check your device permissions."
      );
    }
  }

  async init() {
    this.userMedia = await getUserMedia();
    this.startMediaStream("localVideo", this.userMedia); // Ensure local stream is always shown

    const hubConnection = await signalrStartHubConnection();
    this.signalrHubConnection = ko.observable(hubConnection); // Start the SignalR connection.
    await signalrRegisterWebrtcUserId(hubConnection, this.webrtcUserId());
    this.signalrConnectionId = ko.observable(hubConnection.connectionId); // Store the SignalR connection ID.

    // Bind view model to UI after initialization.
    const viewModel = {
      webrtcUserId: this.webrtcUserId, // Bind WebRTC user ID.
      signalrConnectionId: this.signalrConnectionId, // Bind SignalR connection ID.
      webrtcReceiverUserIdsInputField: this.webrtcReceiverUserIdsInputField, // Bind receiver user IDs input field.
      signalrSenderConnectionId: this.signalrSenderConnectionId, // Bind the SignalR sender connection ID.
      isCallToggled: this.isCallToggled, // Bind the call toggle status.
      toggleCall: this.toggleCall, // Bind the toggle call function.
      acceptCall: this.acceptCall, // Bind with current signal.
      declineCall: this.declineCall, // Bind the decline call function.
    };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel); // Apply Knockout bindings to the view model.
    this.listenForIncomingSignals();
  }

  async toggleCall() {
    const toggleValue = this.isCallToggled();
    if (toggleValue) {
      receiverUserIds = this.receiverUserdIds(); // Get receiver user IDs from input.
      this.startCallMeshUsers();
      receiverUserIds.forEach((userId) => this.startCall(userId));
    } else {
      await this.stopCall();
    }
  }

  async peerConnectionCreateOffer(peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection) {
    try {
      const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
      return offer;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`Error creating peer connection offer: ${error}`);
    }
  }

  async sendOffer(
    signalrHubConnection: signalR.HubConnection,
    receiverUserId: string,
    senderUserId: string,
    data: string
  ) {
    const signalDto: SignalDtoInterface = {
      signalType: SignalTypeEnum.INVITE,
      receiverUserId,
      senderUserId,
      data: data,
      role: RoleEnum.SENDER,
    };

    try {
      await signalrHubConnection.invoke("SendSignal", signalDto);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`Error sending offer to remote peer: ${error}`);
    }
  }

  async sendAnswer(
    signalrHubConnection: signalR.HubConnection,
    receiverUserId: string,
    senderUserId: string,
    data: string
  ) {
    const signalDto: SignalDtoInterface = {
      signalType: SignalTypeEnum.ACCEPT,
      receiverUserId,
      senderUserId,
      data: data,
      role: RoleEnum.RECEIVER,
    };

    try {
      await signalrHubConnection.invoke("SendSignal", signalDto);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`Error sending answer to remote peer: ${error}`);
    }
  }

  async gatherIceCandidates(
    peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection,
    receiverUserId: string
  ) {
    peerConnection.onicecandidate = async (event) => {
      const candidate = event.candidate;
      if (candidate) {
        if (!this.webrtcIceCandidates[receiverUserId]) {
          this.webrtcIceCandidates[receiverUserId] = [candidate];
        } else {
          this.webrtcIceCandidates[receiverUserId].push(candidate);
        }
      }
    };
  }

  parseJson(stringData: string) {
    try {
      return JSON.parse(stringData);
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`Error parsing string data: ${error}`);
    }
  }

  receiverUserdIds(): string[] {
    const inputField = this.webrtcReceiverUserIdsInputField();
    const ids = inputField
      .trim()
      .split(",")
      .map((id) => id.trim())
      .filter((id) => id !== "");
    if (!ids?.length) throw new Error("Error extracting IDs from input field.");
    return ids;
  }

  async startCall(receiverUserId: string) {
    const senderUserId = this.webrtcUserId();
    const config = this.configuration;
    const hubConnection = this.signalrHubConnection();

    const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
    const mediaStream = this.userMedia;

    // Add tracks to the peer connection only if they are not already added.
    mediaStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      const senders = peerConnection.getSenders(); // Get the current senders.
      const isTrackAlreadyAdded = senders.some(
        (sender) => sender.track === track
      ); // Check if track is already added.

      if (!isTrackAlreadyAdded) {
        peerConnection.addTrack(track, mediaStream); // Add the track if it is not already added.
      }
    });

    const offer = await this.peerConnectionCreateOffer(peerConnection);
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);

    this.gatherIceCandidates(peerConnection, receiverUserId);
    this.webrtcPeerConnections[receiverUserId] = peerConnection;

    // // Handle receiving remote media streams.
    this.webrtcPeerConnections[receiverUserId].ontrack = (event) => {
      if (event.streams && event.streams[0]) {
        const stream = event.streams[0];
        this.startMediaStream(
          "remoteVideo_" + receiverUserId,
          event.streams[0]
        ); // Use unique element ID.
      } else {
        console.error("No streams found in the event.");
      }
    };

    // Send the offer to the receiver.
    this.sendOffer(
      hubConnection,
      receiverUserId,
      senderUserId,
      JSON.stringify(offer)
    );
  }

  async stopCall() {
    for (const id in this.webrtcPeerConnections) {
      const peerConnection = this.webrtcPeerConnections[id];
      if (peerConnection) {
        // Close the peer connection and remove senders.
        peerConnection
          .getSenders()
          .forEach((sender) => peerConnection.removeTrack(sender));
        peerConnection.close();
      }
    }
    this.webrtcPeerConnections = {}; // Clear the peer connections map.
  }

  openConfirmationDialog(signal: SignalDtoInterface): void {
    // currentDialogValue = signal;
    const inviteModalElement = document.getElementById("inviteModal");
    if (inviteModalElement) {
      const inviteModal = new Modal(inviteModalElement);
      inviteModal.show();
    }
  }

  closeConfirmationDialog(): void {
    const inviteModalElement = document.getElementById("inviteModal");
    if (inviteModalElement) {
      const inviteModal = Modal.getInstance(inviteModalElement);
      inviteModal?.hide(); // Hide the modal if it's initialized.
    }
  }

  async acceptCall(signal: SignalDtoInterface): Promise<void> {
    const { senderUserId, receiverUserId } = signal;
    const sdpOffer = this.parseJson(signal.data);

    let peerConnection = this.webrtcPeerConnections[senderUserId];
    if (!peerConnection) {
      const config = this.configuration;
      this.webrtcPeerConnections[senderUserId] = new RTCPeerConnection(config);
      peerConnection = this.webrtcPeerConnections[senderUserId];
    }

    const mediaStream = this.userMedia;

    // Add tracks to the peer connection only if they are not already added.
    mediaStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => {
      const senders = peerConnection.getSenders(); // Get all current senders (tracks already added).
      const isTrackAlreadyAdded = senders.some(
        (sender) => sender.track === track
      ); // Check if the track is already added.

      if (!isTrackAlreadyAdded) {
        peerConnection.addTrack(track, mediaStream); // Add the track if it is not already added.
      }
    });

    // Handle the remote track event to receive the incoming media streams.
    this.webrtcPeerConnections[senderUserId].ontrack = (event) => {
      const stream = event.streams;
      if (stream?.length) {
        this.startMediaStream("remoteVideo_" + senderUserId, stream[0]); // Use unique element ID.
      } else {
        console.error("No streams found in the event.");
      }
    };

    await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(sdpOffer);
    const sdpAnswer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
    await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(sdpAnswer);

    const hubConnection = this.signalrHubConnection();
    this.gatherIceCandidates(peerConnection, senderUserId);
    this.sendAnswer(
      hubConnection,
      senderUserId,
      receiverUserId,
      JSON.stringify(sdpAnswer)
    );
  }

  declineCall() {
    this.closeConfirmationDialog();
  }

  listenForIncomingSignals() {
    const hubConnection = this.signalrHubConnection();
    hubConnection.on("ReceiveSignal", async (signal) => {
      const { signalType, receiverUserId, senderUserId } = signal;
      const data = this.parseJson(signal.data);
      this.currentSignal = signal;

      switch (signalType) {
        case SignalTypeEnum.INVITE: {
          let peerConnection = this.webrtcPeerConnections[senderUserId];
          if (!peerConnection) {
            peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(this.configuration);
            this.webrtcPeerConnections[senderUserId] = peerConnection;
          }
          await this.acceptCall(signal);

          break;
        }
        case SignalTypeEnum.ICE_CANDIDATE: {
          if (signal.role === RoleEnum.RECEIVER) {
            data.forEach((candidate: RTCIceCandidate) => {
              this.webrtcPeerConnections[senderUserId].addIceCandidate(
                candidate
              );
            });

            const signalDto: SignalDtoInterface = {
              signalType: SignalTypeEnum.ICE_CANDIDATE,
              receiverUserId: senderUserId,
              senderUserId: receiverUserId,
              data: JSON.stringify(this.webrtcIceCandidates[senderUserId]),
              role: RoleEnum.SENDER,
            };

            try {
              await this.signalrHubConnection().invoke("SendSignal", signalDto);
            } catch (error) {
              throw new Error(`Error sending offer to remote peer: ${error}`);
            }
          } else {
            data.forEach((candidate: RTCIceCandidate) => {
              this.webrtcPeerConnections[senderUserId].addIceCandidate(
                candidate
              );
            });
          }
          break;
        }
        case SignalTypeEnum.ACCEPT: {
          console.log(senderUserId, data);
          await this.webrtcPeerConnections[senderUserId].setRemoteDescription(
            data
          );

          const signalDto: SignalDtoInterface = {
            signalType: SignalTypeEnum.ICE_CANDIDATE,
            receiverUserId: senderUserId,
            senderUserId: receiverUserId,
            data: JSON.stringify(this.webrtcIceCandidates[senderUserId]),
            role: RoleEnum.RECEIVER,
          };

          try {
            await this.signalrHubConnection().invoke("SendSignal", signalDto);
          } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(`Error sending offer to remote peer: ${error}`);
          }
          break;
        }
        case SignalTypeEnum.MESH: {
          await this.startCall(`${data}`);
          break;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  generateCallStructure(ids: string[]) {
    let callStructure: { [key: string]: string[] } = {};

    ids.forEach((user, index) => {
      callStructure[user] = ids.slice(index + 1);
    });

    return callStructure;
  }

  async startCallMeshUsers() {
    const signalDto: SignalDtoInterface = {
      signalType: SignalTypeEnum.MESH,
      receiverUserId: "",
      senderUserId: "",
      data: "",
      role: RoleEnum.SENDER,
    };

    // Iterate over the receiverUserIds asynchronously
    for (const [index, key] of receiverUserIds.entries()) {
      /**
       * 
        "1": ["2", "3", "4"],  // User 1 calls users 2, 3, and 4.
        "2": ["3", "4"],       // User 2 only calls users 3 and 4 (not 1 because 1 has already called).
        "3": ["4"],            // User 3 only calls user 4 (not 1 or 2 because they have already called).
        "4": []                // User 4 doesn't call anyone (all users have already connected).

        NOT:
        1: Array(4) [ "2", "3", "4", … ]
        2: Array(4) [ "1", "3", "4", … ]
        3: Array(4) [ "1", "2", "4", … ]
        4: Array(4) [ "1", "2", "3", … ]
        5: Array(4) [ "1", "2", "3", … ]

       */

      // Filter out users that have already been "called" by this user.
      const mesh: string[] = receiverUserIds.slice(index + 1); // Get users after the current key.

      // Only proceed if there are remaining users to call.
      if (mesh.length > 0) {
        for (const value of mesh) {
          // Set up the signalDto values.
          signalDto.receiverUserId = key; // The current user making the call.
          signalDto.senderUserId = key; // The same user as the sender.
          signalDto.data = value; // The user being called.

          try {
            // Await the asynchronous call to SendSignal.
            await this.signalrHubConnection().invoke("SendSignal", signalDto);
          } catch (error) {
            // Throw an error if the call fails.
            throw new Error(
              `Error calling mesh users: ${JSON.stringify(mesh)}`
            );
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

const conference = new Conference(); // Create a new Conference instance.
conference.init(); // Initialize the conference.


HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WebRTC and SignalR Test</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="./assets/icon/favicon-icon-512x512.png" type="image/x-icon" />

    <!-- Bootstrap 5 CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Tailwind CSS (optional) -->
    <link href="./output.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <!-- Bootstrap 5 JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- SignalR -->

    <!-- Knockout.js CDN -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.0/knockout-min.js'></script>

    <!-- Main JavaScript -->
    <!-- <script src="./main.js" type="module"></script> -->
    <script src="./bundle.js" type="module"></script>
    
    <script src="./lib/signalr/signalr.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="bg-gray-100">
    <!-- Content wrapper. -->
    <div class="m-2 xl:!m-12">
        <!-- Main content container. -->
        <div class="flex xl:flex-row flex-col">
            <!-- Video container. -->
            <div id="videos" class="w-full h-full flex flex-wrap justify-center max-h-max mr-12">
                <div class="w-full">
                    <video id="localVideo" class="w-full bg-black rounded-lg object-contain aspect-video" autoplay playsinline
                        muted></video>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Info and input containers. -->
            <div class="flex flex-col xl:min-w-80 xl:w-1/4 gap-4">
                <div class="flex gap-4 flex-col text-xl border p-4 rounded !min-w-full">
                    <div class="text-center m-auto">
                        <h1 class="font-semibold">My User ID</h1>
                        <p class="w-full p-2 rounded-md text-center select-all text-fuchsia-500" data-bind="text: webrtcUserId">
                            Loading...
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center m-auto">
                        <h1 class="font-semibold">My SignalR Registration ID</h1>
                        <p class="w-full p-2 rounded-md text-center select-all text-fuchsia-500"
                            data-bind="text: signalrConnectionId">
                            Loading...
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input placeholder="IDs (comma separated)" type="text" data-bind="value: webrtcReceiverUserIdsInputField"
                    class="w-full p-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md text-center" />

                <div class="flex justify-center my-4 xl:!my-12">
                    <div class="form-check form-switch !m-0">
                        <input class="cursor-pointer form-check-input scale-150 xl:scale-[3]" type="checkbox" role="switch"
                            id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" data-bind="checked: isCallToggled, event: { change: toggleCall }">
                        </div>
                        </div>

                <div id="logs"
                    class="overflow-y-scroll bg-gray-100 p-3 border border-gray-300 rounded-md font-mono whitespace-pre-wrap h-full">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap 5 Modal for Incoming Call -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="inviteModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="inviteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="inviteModalLabel">Incoming Video Call</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p data-bind="text: signalrSenderConnectionId"></p>
                    <p>Do you want to accept the call?</p>
                    <div class="form-group">
            
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: acceptCall">Accept</button> <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-danger" data-bs-dismiss="modal" data-bind="click: declineCall">Decline</button>
            </div>



    <footer class="px-6 py-2 relative bottom-0 bg-white text-gray-400 w-full m-0 border border-gray-300">
        <ul class="flex gap-4">
            <li>⚡ Barack Obama</li>
            <li><a href="https://youtube.com">YouTube</a></li>
        </ul>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>

Can someone please help me solve this problem? I have no idea where it goes wrong and I don't receive any error messages in the console. Both on the sender and receiver's side.
I tried restructuring the code. Placing await and removing await. And reordering code. I also tried different browsers and checking all my permissions (camera & mic).
